# How to use dropdowns bootstrap in an angular project

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have installed bootstrap 5 in my angular project and everything is in place, I imported `NgModule` in `app.module.routing`, but when I use the code for the dropdown, it gives me nothing. I am using `angular 11`.
Can someone please help me, here's the code I'm trying to use as an example :

```html
<div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown button
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `popper.js` is included as it is required for all things that pop up or drop down in `Bootstrap 4`.

Below is what the relevant part of `angular.json` should look like:

```
"architect": {
 "build": {
  ...
  "options: {
   "styles": [
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
      "src/styles.css"
    ],
    "scripts": [
      "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
      "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    ],
    ...
    }
  }
  ...
 }
```

To install `popper.js` use this command:

```
npm install popper.js --save
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can also add these lines to the end of the body balise of the HTML file
      <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
      <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```